# Add a new UIToolbar to UIViewController

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uitoolbar, uitoolbaritem

I'm developing a TabBar based application with an UIViewController witch appear when a cell is selected in the first view. I would like to add an UIToolBar with some informations (in the items) given by the segue of the selected cell. I already tried the code bellow (found in a similar question) but it doesn't work :

```
if (self) {
    NSArray* toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd 
                                                                           target:self
                                                                           action:@selector(addStuff:)],
                             [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch 
                                                                           target:self
                                                                           action:@selector(searchStuff:)],
                             nil];
    [self setToolbarItems:toolbarItems];
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated: YES];

}
return self;
```

Does anyone knows another way to add a new UIToolBar over the one inferred by the Navigation Controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding an IBOutlet UIToolBar and defining it as the view's toolbar.
 `theToolBar = [[self navigationController] toolbar];`